# Flink object reuse: modify input objects?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Flink streaming application that spends roughly 20% of its CPU time in Kyro.copy. I can evade that by turning on object reuse mode, but I have a slight problem: I'd like to modify input objects to my operators.

The general contract for object reuse mode seems to state: Do not modify input objects or remember input objects after returning from your map function. You may modify objects after `output` and re-emit them. (e.g.: [Slide 6](https://github.com/ververica/flink-training-troubleshooting/blob/master/slides/2019-10-07%20_%20TROUBLESHOOTING%20_%207%20OBJECT%20REUSE.pdf))

Now, my question is: If I immediately dispose of all references to objects after `output`-ing them from my operators, is it safe to modify input objects? Or is there some other combination of rules that can make it safe to modify input objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it would be safe. But note that immediate disposal also means that you cannot use them as a key in maps and that also means heap state backends (you can use it for lookup, but would need to create a copy on modification). So for simple map chains, it should work well, but before using joins, windows, and grouping, I'd double check it or create my own defensive copies at appropriate places.

Btw, if you want to improve performance, it's almost always recommended to ditch Kryo serialization. Kryo would slow down any network traffic if you have any. If so, try to use POJOs, some well-supported formats like Avro, or write your own serializer. That would certainly improve performance more than object reuse. This paragraph does not apply if you don't have any network channels.

Comment: Sadly, these messages are ("dynamic"?) JSON and I think there's little I can do to make them into more than a `Map<String, Object>`. So no choice but Kryo? That aside, I'm curious: Even if I don't have any network channels, I'd still get `Kryo.copy` with multiple operators. So (excluding GC), the cost would roughly halve, but not be 0?

Comment: If the value type is fixed (always string), you could use Flinks map serializer or even Avro's map. If not, you are stuck where you are. I always recommend to not use dynamic JSON (e.g. schemaless) and invest the time to carve out schemas to save storage, CPU, and make development nicer, but if you don't have control over the source, you are doomed.

Comment: `Kryo.copy` is usually used between chained operators if object reuse is disabled. But also on broadcasts and joins you need to replicate elements if object reuse is enabled (pretty much everywhere where one reused record is not immediately consumed).